# Faster read from GPKG to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, gdal, ogr2ogr, geopackage

I am loading data from a GPKG to a PostGIS database using GDAL and have noticed that it is very slow even with using the normal faster tricks. I am currently using this command

```
ogr2ogr -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES -gt 65000 -f PostgreSQL PG:"" data.gpkg -nln output -nlt POLYGON -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=None
```

it has taken over 20 minutes to load in 65000 features.

Writing the other way is very quick so it seems to be the read from GPKG is bad.

Is there anything else I can try or do to improve the read rate?

Comment: which OS are you on? are they big polygons? do you have an index on the table already?

Comment: Windows, PostgreSQL 12 PostGIS 3, GDAL 3.1, problem applies to both polygons and line tables

Comment: 12Gb - i am already using PG_USE_COPY and the gt switch

Comment: You can test your assumption about the bottleneck with `ogr2ogr -progress -gt 65000 -f GPKG copy.gpkg data.gpkg -nln output -lco SPATIAL_INDEX=NO`. And/Or by converting GPKG data into shapefile and then into PostGIS.

Comment: @user30184 thank you for that great idea. Going GPKG to GPKG is super fast so I dug deeper and it seems when loading to PostGIS the table it creates adds a primary key before loading. So tested using a blank table and load into that and its take ~12 minutes to load 700k records. Thank you

Comment: @tjmgis this is a worthwhile solution - could you add this as an answer explaining further?